polymorphic *_type problem with repository pattern in laravel
I need some help with a polymorphic many-to-many relationship. I am using the controller-service-repository pattern. The problem occurs when I write a query in ProjectRepo that extends Project. In the query log, the equipmentable_type is bindings to  APP/Domain/Project/ProjectRepo instead of APP/Domain/Project/Project.
There is no difference if I use:
static::whereId($id)->with('equipment')->first();
or
Project::whereId($id)->with('equipment')->first();
However, outside of ProjectRepo, if I use:
Project::whereId($id)->with('equipment')->first();
or in Project Model itself ,
the problem is solved and the equipment is returned correctly.
Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?
Thank you!

Here’s how I solved it:

Define MorphMap in AppServiceProvider (or a custom service provider), add the following in the boot function:

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
    Relation::morphMap([
        Project::class => ProjectRepo::class,
        WorkRequest::class => WorkRequestRepo::class,
        PlannedWork::class => PlannedWorkRepo::class,
    ]);


Create a Custom MorphPivot Class extends MorphPivot:

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

    class Equipmentable extends MorphPivot
    {
        protected $table = 'equipmentables';
        public $incrementing = true;
    }


Define the Polymorphic Relationship Using the Custom Pivot Class:

In my Project model (or the relevant model), I defined the polymorphic relationship using the custom pivot class:
    public function equipments(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Equipment::class, 'equipmentable')->using(Equipmentable::class);
    }

Now enjoy polymorphic relations with the repository pattern without encountering the binding issue !
